# SQL DateDiff advanced usage?

Tags: sql, datediff

I need to calculate the DateDiff (hours) between two dates, but only during business-hours (8:30 - 16:00, no weekends). This result will then be put into the Reaction_Time column as per the example below.

```
ID           Date           Reaction_Time   Overdue
1    29.04.2003 15:00:00                      
1    30.04.2003 11:00:00        3:30        
2    30.04.2003 14:00:00                      
2    01.05.2003 14:00:00        7:30          YES
```

*Note: I didn't check to see if the dates in example were holidays.

I'm using SQL Server 2005

This will be combined with a bigger query, but for now all I need is this to get started, I'll try to figure out how to put it all together on my own. Thanks for the help!

**Edit:** Hey, thanks everyone for the replies. But due to the obvious complexity of a solution on SQL side, it was decided we would do this in Excel instead as that's where the report will be moved anyway. Sorry for the trouble, but I really figured it would be simpler than this. As it is, we just don't have the time.

Comment: i didn't quite get the question

Comment: Me neither. Read it a few times now to no avail. Can you at least give us some of the data in the original table? Ideally the data that makes your example result plausible.

Comment: i guess he wants to do a DateDiff on the rows with the same ID, but only count BUSINESS HOURS

Comment: @Zan: You don't have the time to move one of the working solutions posted here to your database, but you *do* have the time to implement something from scratch in Excel? I don't get it...

Comment: @Tomalak: Excel isn't my job, there's an expert in the house who can do all that. I'm working in internship and the time I need to do the most basic of tasks is too much as it is, so sometimes I need to cut corners to meet the DL's. Sorry if you took offense, I do appreciate the help though.

Comment: Thing is that where you see an obvious and ready response, I might see SQL so complex it takes me a full day to even understand what it actually does. I really figured this would be simpler. I'll try to use the responses here as best as I can but I can't fight the rush I'm being put through here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @BusHourStart DATETIME, @BusHourEnd DATETIME
SELECT @BusHourStart = '08:30:00', @BusHourEnd = '16:00:00'
DECLARE @BusMinutesStart INT, @BusMinutesEnd INT
SELECT @BusMinutesStart = DATEPART(minute,@BusHourStart)+DATEPART(hour,@BusHourStart)*60, 
@BusMinutesEnd = DATEPART(minute,@BusHourEnd)+DATEPART(hour,@BusHourEnd)*60 
DECLARE @Dates2 TABLE (ID INT, DateStart DATETIME, DateEnd DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Dates2
SELECT 1, '15:00:00 04/29/2003', '11:00:00 04/30/2003' UNION
SELECT 2, '14:00:00 04/30/2003', '14:00:00 05/01/2003' UNION
SELECT 3, '14:00:00 05/02/2003', '14:00:00 05/06/2003' UNION
SELECT 4, '14:00:00 05/02/2003', '14:00:00 05/04/2003' UNION
SELECT 5, '07:00:00 05/02/2003', '14:00:00 05/02/2003' UNION
SELECT 6, '14:00:00 05/02/2003', '23:00:00 05/02/2003' UNION
SELECT 7, '07:00:00 05/02/2003', '08:00:00 05/02/2003' UNION
SELECT 8, '22:00:00 05/02/2003', '23:00:00 05/03/2003' UNION
SELECT 9, '08:00:00 05/03/2003', '23:00:00 05/04/2003' UNION
SELECT 10, '07:00:00 05/02/2003', '23:00:00 05/02/2003' 

-- SET DATEFIRST to U.S. English default value of 7.
SET DATEFIRST 7

SELECT ID, DateStart, DateEnd, CONVERT(VARCHAR, Minutes/60) +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, Minutes % 60) AS ReactionTime
FROM ( 
    SELECT ID, DateStart, DateEnd, Overtime,
        CASE 
            WHEN DayDiff = 0 THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN (MinutesEnd - MinutesStart - Overtime) > 0 THEN (MinutesEnd - MinutesStart - Overtime) 
                    ELSE 0 
                    END
            WHEN DayDiff > 0  THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN (StartPart + EndPart - Overtime) > 0 THEN (StartPart + EndPart - Overtime) 
                    ELSE 0 
                    END + DayPart
            ELSE 0
        END AS Minutes 
    FROM(
        SELECT ID, DateStart, DateEnd, DayDiff, MinutesStart, MinutesEnd,
                CASE WHEN(@BusMinutesStart - MinutesStart) > 0 THEN (@BusMinutesStart - MinutesStart) ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN(MinutesEnd - @BusMinutesEnd) > 0 THEN (MinutesEnd - @BusMinutesEnd) ELSE 0 END AS Overtime, 
                CASE WHEN(@BusMinutesEnd - MinutesStart) > 0 THEN (@BusMinutesEnd - MinutesStart) ELSE 0 END AS StartPart,
                CASE WHEN(MinutesEnd - @BusMinutesStart) > 0 THEN (MinutesEnd - @BusMinutesStart) ELSE 0 END AS EndPart,
                CASE WHEN DayDiff > 1 THEN (@BusMinutesEnd - @BusMinutesStart)*(DayDiff - 1) ELSE 0 END AS DayPart
        FROM (
                SELECT DATEDIFF(d,DateStart, DateEnd) AS DayDiff, ID, DateStart, DateEnd,  
                DATEPART(minute,DateStart)+DATEPART(hour,DateStart)*60 AS MinutesStart,
                DATEPART(minute,DateEnd)+DATEPART(hour,DateEnd)*60 AS MinutesEnd 
                FROM (
                        SELECT ID,
                                CASE 
                                        WHEN DATEPART(dw, DateStart) = 7 
                                        THEN DATEADD(SECOND, 1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateStart), 2))
                                        WHEN DATEPART(dw, DateStart) = 1 
                                        THEN DATEADD(SECOND, 1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateStart), 1))
                                ELSE DateStart END AS DateStart,
                                CASE 
                                        WHEN DATEPART(dw, DateEnd) = 7 
                                        THEN DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateEnd), 0))
                                        WHEN DATEPART(dw, DateEnd) = 1 
                                        THEN DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateEnd), -1))
                                ELSE DateEnd END AS DateEnd FROM @Dates2
                )Weekends
        )InMinutes
    )Overtime
)Calculation
```

Comment: Is there a way I can copy this code without loosing the carraige returns and other white space?

Comment: Okay, let me emphasise something here :)  I asked how to "copy this code without loosing the carraige returns and other white space", this implies that my monkey like abilities extended far enough to trying to copy and paste.  But I keep loosing the carriage returns, etc :)

Comment: A normal copy/paste always works for me - whitespace and all.

Comment: IE 7.0 - My employer "actively discourages" installation of any alternative

Comment: yeh, it's an browser issue. Tried with IE - indeed all formatting of code block is lost.

Comment: @Dems: View page source, copy from there.

Comment: @coldice: Shouldn't "2003-04-29 15:00"-"2003-04-30 11:00" be "4:30h" instead of "3:30"? And "2003-05-02 22:00"-"2003-05-02 23:59" is "-6:0h" with your solution, this can hardly be. ;-) Apart from that, +1 from me, nice solution.

Comment: thanks Tomalak, work time set to 08:30 - 16:00, so it's ok. bug with negative hours - fixed, commited :)

Comment: Oh, than the error is in my solution, my work time is set wrong. Meh. I'll go and correct mine as well.

Comment: I did a little performance test on a table of 1.000.000 random rows. Over a three times average on my machine the query based version took 47 seconds, the function based version took 25 seconds.

Comment: sounds great, stored execution plan rules!

Comment: Erm, I was referring to your answer as the "query based version" and to my answer as the "function based version". Stored execution plans have nothing to do with the difference. ;-)

Comment: well, I also talked about both your & mine versions... but you right, plan isn't sognificant in this case. one of the 'bottlenacks' in my query is "CONVERT(VARCHAR, Minutes/60) +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, Minutes % 60)". :) replace it with "Minutes", and youll see the difference

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend building a user defined function that calculates the date difference in business hours according to your rules.

```
SELECT
  Id,
  MIN(Date) DateStarted,
  MAX(Date) DateCompleted,
  dbo.udfDateDiffBusinessHours(MIN(Date), MAX(Date)) ReactionTime
FROM
  Incident
GROUP BY
  Id
```

I'm not sure where your `Overdue` value comes from, so I left it off in my example.

In a function you can write way more expressive SQL than in a query, and you don't clog your query with business rules, making it hard to maintain.

Also a function can easily be reused. Extending it to include support for holidays (I'm thinking of a `Holidays` table here) would not be too hard. Further refinements are possible without the need to change hard to read nested SELECT/CASE WHEN constructs, which would be the alternative.

If I have time today, I'll look into writing an example function.

---

EDIT: Here is something with bells and whistles, calculating around weekends transparently:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.udfDateDiffBusinessHours (
  @date1 DATETIME,
  @date2 DATETIME
) RETURNS DATETIME AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sat INT
  DECLARE @sun INT
  DECLARE @workday_s INT
  DECLARE @workday_e INT
  DECLARE @basedate1 DATETIME
  DECLARE @basedate2 DATETIME
  DECLARE @calcdate1 DATETIME
  DECLARE @calcdate2 DATETIME
  DECLARE @cworkdays INT
  DECLARE @cweekends INT
  DECLARE @returnval INT

  SET @workday_s = 510 -- work day start:  8.5 hours
  SET @workday_e = 960 -- work day end:   16.0 hours

    -- calculate Saturday and Sunday dependent on SET DATEFIRST option
  SET @sat = CASE @@DATEFIRST WHEN 7 THEN 7 ELSE 7 - @@DATEFIRST END 
  SET @sun = CASE @@DATEFIRST WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE @sat + 1 END 

  SET @calcdate1 = @date1
  SET @calcdate2 = @date2

  -- @date1: assume next day if start was after end of workday
  SET @basedate1 = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @calcdate1))
  SET @calcdate1 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, @basedate1, @calcdate1) > @workday_e
                   THEN @basedate1 + 1
                   ELSE @calcdate1
                   END

  -- @date1: if Saturday or Sunday, make it next Monday
  SET @basedate1 = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @calcdate1))
  SET @calcdate1 = CASE DATEPART(dw, @basedate1)
                   WHEN @sat THEN @basedate1 + 2
                   WHEN @sun THEN @basedate1 + 1
                   ELSE @calcdate1
                   END

  -- @date1: assume @workday_s as the minimum start time
  SET @basedate1 = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @calcdate1))
  SET @calcdate1 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, @basedate1, @calcdate1) < @workday_s 
                   THEN DATEADD(mi, @workday_s, @basedate1)
                   ELSE @calcdate1
                   END

  -- @date2: assume previous day if end was before start of workday
  SET @basedate2 = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @calcdate2))
  SET @calcdate2 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, @basedate2, @calcdate2) < @workday_s
                   THEN @basedate2 - 1
                   ELSE @calcdate2
                   END

  -- @date2: if Saturday or Sunday, make it previous Friday
  SET @basedate2 = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @calcdate2))
  SET @calcdate2 = CASE DATEPART(dw, @calcdate2)
                   WHEN @sat THEN @basedate2 - 0.00001
                   WHEN @sun THEN @basedate2 - 1.00001
                   ELSE @date2
                   END

  -- @date2: assume @workday_e as the maximum end time
  SET @basedate2 = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @calcdate2))
  SET @calcdate2 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, @basedate2, @calcdate2) > @workday_e
                   THEN DATEADD(mi, @workday_e, @basedate2)
                   ELSE @calcdate2
                   END

  -- count full work days (subtract Saturdays and Sundays)
  SET @cworkdays = DATEDIFF(dd, @basedate1, @basedate2)
  SET @cweekends = @cworkdays / 7
  SET @cworkdays = @cworkdays - @cweekends * 2

  -- calculate effective duration in minutes
  SET @returnval = @cworkdays * (@workday_e - @workday_s)
                   + @workday_e - DATEDIFF(mi, @basedate1, @calcdate1) 
                   + DATEDIFF(mi, @basedate2, @calcdate2) - @workday_e

  -- return duration as an offset in minutes from date 0
  RETURN DATEADD(mi, @returnval, 0)
END
```

The function returns a `DATETIME` value meant as an offset from date 0 (which is `"1900-01-01 00:00:00"`). So for example a timespan of 8:00 hours would be `"1900-01-01 08:00:00"` and 25 hours would be `"1900-01-02 01:00:00"`. The function result is the time *difference in business* hours between two dates. No special handling/support for overtime.

```
SELECT dbo.udfDateDiffBusinessHours('2003-04-29 15:00:00', '2003-04-30 11:00:00')
--> 1900-01-01 03:30:00.000

SELECT dbo.udfDateDiffBusinessHours('2003-04-30 14:00:00', '2003-05-01 14:00:00')
--> 1900-01-01 07:30:00.000
```

The function assumes the start of the next available work day (08:30 h) when the `@date1` is off-hours, and the end of the previous available work day (16:00 h) when `@date2` is off-hours.

"next/previous available" means:

- if `@date1` is `'2009-02-06 07:00:00'` (Fri), it will become `'2009-02-06 08:30:00'` (Fri)
- if `@date1` is `'2009-02-06 19:00:00'` (Fri), it will become `'2009-02-09 08:30:00'` (Mon)
- if `@date2` is `'2009-02-09 07:00:00'` (Mon), it will become `'2009-02-06 16:00:00'` (Fri)
- if `@date2` is `'2009-02-09 19:00:00'` (Mon), it will become `'2009-02-09 16:00:00'` (Mon)

Comment: We don't have any business-hour reference calendars here, that's why I support your idea of being able to create the rules myself. I don't have the permission to add tables to the DB, so the functions etc will have to be created within the same query. But thanks, I'll look into this. :)

Comment: The layout and comments are great in this solution.  It doesn't work for me though because it assumes at least one week has passed (SET @cweekends = @cworkdays / 7).  If the interval is Thursday through Tuesday, no weekends are factored in.  I may try to alter this query though.  If I get it working for my situation I'll post and give appropriate credit to you Tomalak.  I'm not nearly as skilled in SQL though so no promises!  :)

Comment: Posted my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503749/tsql-function-to-find-difference-between-two-dates-taking-weekends-and-holidays-i

Comment: I modified this to make an "shipped within company's SLA" report.  Great job!

Answer (score 1):

```
select datediff(hh,@date1,@date2) - 16.5*(datediff(dd,@date1,@date2))
```

The only catch is that it will give you 3:30 as 3.5 hours but you can fix that easily.

Comment: What if the second event was at 17:00?  It doesn't state in the question if that is possible or not.  Your answer seems fine if it's not possible :)

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't recognize the actual start and end times, or something.

For example, if @date1 = '2009/01/2 16:00', and @date2 = '2009/1/3 09:00' the datediff returns 0.5 hours. But if I change date one clock to 15:30, it returns 1.5 hours when it should be just 1. How come?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code : to find out weekend in between dates

```
 (
    DATEDIFF(dd, open_date, zassignment_date) + 1 
    - ( (DATEDIFF(dd, open_date, zassignment_date) + 1) 
    -(DATEDIFF(wk, open_date, zassignment_date) * 2) 
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw,  open_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, zassignment_date) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) )) wk_end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reference-table of the working days (and their hours), then I would use a 3 stage approach (pseudo-sql)

(first preclude the "all in one day" trivial example, since that simplifies the logic)

```
 -- days that are neither the start nor end (full days)
 SELECT @FullDayHours = SUM(day start to day end)
 FROM   reference-calendar
 WHERE  Start >= midnight-after-start and End <= midnight-before-end

 -- time after the [query start] to the end of the first working day
 SELECT @FirstDayHours = [query start] to day end
 FROM   reference-calandar
 WHERE  start day

 -- time from the start of the last working day to the [query end]
 SELECT @LastDayHours = day start to [query end]
 FROM   reference-calendar
 WHERE  end-day

 IF @FirstDayHours < 0 SET @FirstDayHours = 0 -- starts outside working time
 IF @LastDayHours < 0 SET @LastDayHours  = 0 -- ends outside working time

 PRINT @FirstDayHours  + @FullDayHours + @LastDayHours
```

Obviously it is a bit hard to do properly without more context...

Comment: That's fine if you want just a single answer, what if you want to process a whole table?

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you the difference in business hours between two given times. This will return the difference in minutes or hours based on the date part parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBusinessHoursDateDiff] (@StartTime SmallDatetime, @EndTime SmallDateTime, @DatePart varchar(2)) RETURNS DECIMAL (10,2)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @Minutes        bigint
    ,   @FinalNumber    Decimal(10,2)

-- // Create Minute By minute table for CTE
-- ===========================================================
;WITH  cteInputHours (StartTime, EndTime, NextTime) AS (
    SELECT  @StartTime  
        ,   @EndTime    
        ,   dateadd(mi, 1, @StartTime)
 ),
 cteBusinessMinutes (TimeOfDay, [isBusHour], NextTime) AS(
    SELECT  StartTime [TimeOfDay]
        ,   case when datepart(dw, StartTime) between 2 and 6 and convert(time,StartTime) between '08:30' and '15:59' then 1 else 0 end [isBusHour]
        ,   dateadd(mi, 1, @StartTime)  [NextTime]
    FROM    cteInputHours
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  dateadd(mi, 1, (a.TimeOfDay)) [TimeOfDay]
        ,   case when datepart(dw, a.TimeOfDay) between 2 and 6 and  convert(time,dateadd(mi, 1, (a.TimeOfDay)) ) between '08:30' and '15:59' then 1 else 0 end [isBusHour]
        ,   dateadd(mi, 2, (a.TimeOfDay)) NextTime
    FROM    cteBusinessMinutes a
    WHERE   dateadd(mi, 1, (a.TimeOfDay)) < @EndTime
) 
SELECT  @Minutes = count(*)
FROM    cteBusinessMinutes
WHERE   isBusHour = 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

-- // Final Select
-- ===========================================================
SELECT  @FinalNumber = @Minutes / (case when @DatePart = 'hh' then 60.00 else 1 end)

RETURN @FinalNumber 

END
```