# Days between max date in each group

Tags: sql, datediff, rank

I want to find out the number of days between each order. I have the date each order was placed and a reference to show if its their first, second third etc order

What I want to see if how many days there was between order 1 and 2, then how many days between 2 and 3 and so on.

```
select OrderID, OrderDate, RankOrder
from Orders
```

Some example data would be:

```
Order 1 -> 01/01/2015 -> 1
Order 2 -> 03/01/2015 -> 2
Order 3 -> 10/01/2015 -> 3
```

I'd want the results to have an extra column with the number of days:

```
Order 1 -> 01/01/2015 -> 1 -> 2
Order 2 -> 03/01/2015 -> 2 -> 7
Order 3 -> 10/01/2015 -> 3 -> 0
```

The last order would probably look at the current date to work out the datediff.

Comment: Tag dbms product used. When it comes to date/time too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL DateDiff advanced usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593898/sql-datediff-advanced-usage)

Comment: That one didn't really look to get resolved as the edit says they just used excel in the end anyway. Maybe ill have to think of another way to work this out, i'm trying to work out consecutive blocks but weekends are causing me issues. This was just a simplified version of what I was trying to do.

Comment: Tag dbms product used. Some common dbms don't offer LAG/LEAD which would really simplify the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the ranking function, this is just a join with date arithmetic.  Using SQL Server's `datediff()` function, this looks like:

```
select o.*,
       datediff(day, o.OrderDate,
                coalesce(onext.OrderDate, getdate()) as diff
from orders o left join
     orders onext
     on o.rankorder = onext.rankorder - 1;
```

The date arithmetic depends on the database.

Comment: Its seams so obvious now ive seen the answer, just tried this and its worked great. Thanks